# How do I sort using the grep and sort commands?

Tags: shell, pipe

I would like to create a sorted list of all TCP services found in the file `/etc/services`, pipe the output of the command `grep tcp /etc/services` into the command `sort`, then redirect the output of this pipe into the file `~/pipelab.txt`.

I keep getting an error message that my output is wrong, and I don't know why.

This is what I've tried last:

```
grep tcp /etc/services > ~/pipelab.txt | sort
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`> ~/pipelab.txt` obviously belongs to the command on the same side of the pipeline operator `|`. I.e. you redirect the `grep` output to the file instead of piping it into `sort`:

```
grep tcp /etc/services | sort > ~/pipelab.txt
```

Answer (score 34):

You're trying to both redirect the output of `grep` to a file *and* pipe it to `sort`. You can't do that, at least not like that.

Instead, you really just want to feed it to sort:

```
grep tcp /etc/services | sort
```

and then you want to redirect the *sorted* output (i.e., what's coming out of sort) to a file, so you put the redirect after sort:

```
grep tcp /etc/services | sort > ~/pipelab.txt
```

Both pipes and redirects work by changing where the output of the command goes. You had two of them fighting over the output from `grep` (and ultimately, the redirect won, and wrote the unsorted output to your file).

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought as long as I put the sort command in anywhere it would still work.

Comment: @user72510 Pipelines are processed in order, from left to right. That's actually useful, for example if you want the first five lines of the sorted output, you could do `grep tcp /etc/services | sort | head -n 5`. Its important the `sort` be done before the `head`, or you'd not get the lines you want.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. I am taking the class online so I am teaching myself. Adding to it that I am 40 it is slow learning.